# setting default value for react class component state in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is the state of the component:

```
class Feed extends Component<FeedProps, FeedState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isEditing: false,
      posts: [],
      totalPosts: 0,
      editPost: null,
      status: "",
      postPage: 1,
      postsLoading: true,
      editLoading: false,
    };
  }
      
  return (jsx code here)}
```

this is the interface that I wrote:

```
interface FeedState {
  isEditing: boolean;
  posts: typeof Post[];
  totalPosts: 0;
  editPost: null | boolean;
  status: string;
  postPage: 1;
  postsLoading: boolean;
  editLoading: boolean;
}
```

i need to set default value for totalPosts and postpage but I could not figure out. Also

```
 posts: typeof Post[]; // Post is a functional component and i try to say posts is gonna be array of Post instances. is it correct or shall I convert Post to class component.
```

I am getting these errors:

```
      Types of property 'totalPosts' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.
      Type '{ posts: React.FC<PostProps>[]; totalPosts: number; }' is not assignable to type 'FeedState | Pick<FeedState, "posts" | "totalPosts">'.
```

I am in the middle of converting my js project to tsx and i cannot run the code yet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you seeing an error? What do you mean "I could not figure it out?"

Comment: Hi @jered . yes Iam getting errors and i updated the question. sorry for not being clear. I have lost myself inside react-typescript

Answer (score 1):

`totalPosts` and `postPage` should be of type `number`, not the literal values of `0` and `1`. There is no way to set a "default value" directly on an interface, you have to do it in the initialization of the class itself (which it looks like you are already doing).

As for `Post[]`, it would be an anti-pattern in React to keep instances of React components directly in state. Instead, you should keep the data that those instances represent, the *model*, in state, and render components based off of that.

So instead of doing this:

```
function Post({ title }) {
  // etc.
}

// bad, very bad
this.setState({posts: [<Post title="Hello" />]});

// render function...
render () {
  return <div>{this.state.posts}</div>
}
```

You should do this:

```
// much better
this.setState({posts: [{ title: "Hello" }] });

// render function...
render () {
  return <div>{this.state.posts.map(ea => <Post {...ea} />)}</div>
}
```

Then in your interface, the type of `posts` would be something like `Array<{title: string}>`, or if you want to be fancy, `Array<Partial<React.ComponentProps<typeof Post>>>`

React components should turn state and data into something to render, NOT by keeping instances of components in variables or state itself, but instead by *transforming* state into a rendered component.